# Puppeteer - Connecting to HTTPS website through a proxy with authentication doesn't work

Tags: authentication, https, proxy, puppeteer, headless-browser

I have been trying to solve this issue for the past 2 days and haven't been able to. I've looked this up everywhere and still no solution.. Here's the code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');
const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth');

puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());

const PROXY_SERVER_IP = 'IP.IP.IP.IP';
const PROXY_SERVER_PORT = '1234';
const PROXY_USERNAME = 'username';
const PROXY_PASSWORD = 'password';

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: [`--proxy-server=http://${PROXY_SERVER_IP}:${PROXY_SERVER_PORT}`],
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.authenticate({
    username: PROXY_USERNAME,
    password: PROXY_PASSWORD,
  });

  await page.goto('https://www.google.ca/', {
    timeout: 0,
  });

  await page.screenshot({ path: 'test4.png', fullPage: true });

  await browser.close();
})();
```

I get a navigation timeout error on the page.goto() call because it just hangs for some reason. I can't figure out why. When I put a proxy that doesn't require authentication, it works. I'm thinking of switching to another headless solution because of this one issue and I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: I know that playwright has proxy auth for at least chromium and firefox.

Comment: I think that the problem is setting http authentication instead of proxy authentication. Try to use the address: `http://user::password@ip:port`, e.g: `http://leo:some%40password@192.168.15.80:3128` (password must be encoded with `encodeURIComponent`) , or use the `Proxy-Authentication` http header. Look here: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/676

Comment: @pguardiario Thanks for the suggestion I was actually looking at playwright and might switch over.

Comment: @Leo I already tried that header solution but didn't work :/. And can you expand on what you mean when you say " the problem is setting http authentication instead of proxy authentication"?

Comment: @pguardiario Okay so I just tried this with Playwright and I get the exact same issue! I know the proxy isn't an issue because I can issue a cURL request through it to https://google.com and everything works fine..

Comment: You have to follow the documentation for where to put that, I don't know it offhand.

Comment: @pguardiario What do you mean? I followed the documentation for Playwright and I still got the same navigation timeout error. Also, I just tried to use Axios to do the same thing and it worked there as well. So there seems to be something wrong with these headless browser libraries because I can go through the proxy using other methods like cURL and Axios...

Comment: @TheMAAAN Sorry, I'm just wrong about the http-auth/proxy-auth, the headers can be used for both authentications.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out. Turns out the proxy was really bad for some reason. The reason why Axios and cURL gave fast responses was because they just get the initial HTML code and unlike headless browsers, don't actually do anything with HTML text. With headless browsers, they actually make all the requests for the assets as well (css, images, etc.) and any other network requests and it's all going through the proxy, so it's much slower. When I tried a different proxy (one that requires authentication), it was much faster.